# как получить имя пользователя компьютера подключенного к OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

я использовал командлет `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * | Sort LastLogonDate | Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate -Autosize`. он выводит мне имя компа по типа ca-nb-57 и дату входа. а мне нужно имя пользователя за этим компом по типу 'IvanovAS'

Comment: https://doma35.ru/computers/kto-zaloginen-na-udalennom-kompyutere-powershell/

Comment: оно выдает имена компов, а мне нужен логин пользователя под именем этого компа

Comment: Статью попробуйте прочесть на которую я вам ссылку дал. Там ответ на ваш вопрос есть  100% :) зашел и проверил... ```Get-WmiObject -ComputerName 'localhost' -Class win32_L.....```

Comment: Get-WmiObject -ComputerName 'localhost' -Class win32_ComputerSystem | Select-object UserName
вы про эту команду? там нет такой которую вы написали с таким концом `-Class win32_L.....`

Comment: Если ее нет в статье по ctrl-f - это вполне логично, статья для осознания и чтения, все команды там в виде картинок, чтоб вы поняли как это делать а не для копипасты :) там даже есть оглавление, и целая глава о том как получать активные сессии NT из AD

Comment: эта команда выводит имя только моего компьютера а другое имя в домене не видит